# Why does rand(variable) halt my Shoes program's execution?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am brand new to Shoes, and am trying to create a simple dice roller that allows the user to choose a custom-sized die by inputting the number of sides.  My code is as follows:

```
Shoes.app :width => 500, :height => 300 do
 flow do
   para "Sides: "
   @sides = edit_line
 end
 flow do
   button "Roll!" do
     @total = 1 + rand(sides)
     alert @total
   end
 end
end
```

I input a number in the edit line, click the button, and nothing happens.

If I replace `@total = rand(sides)` with `@total = rand(20)`, the program executes just fine, but of course only produces random numbers from 1-20.

I tried variations like `rand(@sides)`, to no avail.

I designed a similar program in just plain Ruby which uses  `rand(sides)` without a problem, but if I try to do it in Shoes, it does nothing.

Comment: +1 for @AShelly: `@total = 1 + rand(sides)` should be `@total = 1 + rand(@sides)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple mistakes. First, use `@sides`, not `sides`. That way, you're referencing the same variable you set earlier.

Second, the type of `@sides` is `Shoes::EditLine`. Which is good, since you need to look up the text dynamically. When you want the text of `@sides`, call `@sides.text`, which returns a `String`. Of course, in this context, you'll need to convert that to an integer suitable for input to `rand`, so you'll use `@sides.text.to_i`.

(Of course, the standard don't-trust-users caveats apply. In reality, you'll want to check your input for invalid input and do something useful.)

Long story short, replace `@total = 1 + rand(sides)` with `@total = 1 + rand(@sides.text.to_i)` and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

`edit_line` returns a String object. You need to convert it to integer first with `@sides = edit_line.to_i`